# Target Unreachable, identifier 'userBean' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, cdi, managed-bean, propertynotfoundexception

- There are two ways to configure managed beans, one is Using the "faces-config.xml" file, another is using "annotations".
- So in this demo, I want to configure beans using annotations in MyEclipse, but it didn't work.
- Here is the code:

---

1.UserBean.java

```
public class UserBean {
String userid;
String password;

@Named("userBean")
@RequestScoped
public String getUserid() {
    return userid;
}
public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}}
```

2.Login.xhtml
[the page users enter the id and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghi0T.png)

3.Welcome.xhtml
[when user click the submit button, the page comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Q6o.png)

4.faces-config.xml
[faces-config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu3xN.png)

---

As you can see, I didn't configure the managed bean in the "faces-config.xml" file, I just use "@Named("userBean")" and "@RequestScoped" in my "UserBean.java" file to configure the bean.

---

1.I open the login.xhtml on the website

[http://localhost:8080/JSF/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcNSc.png)

---

2.When I click the button to submit the data, it comes up this page:

[After click the submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRutC.png)

---

I started to learn JSF these days, there are many confused things I need to figure out, thanks a lot if you can give me some notes or guidance on this question ^_^

---

(Ps.This is the first question I ask on stackoverflow, so I couldn't upload pictures directly, if you cannot see the pictures by hperlinks, please let me know.Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `@Named` bean annotation to the class instead of the method.
The error basically says that server failed to find the managed bean class. So your code should be like:

```
@Named("userBean")
@RequestScoped 
public class UserBean {
    String userid;
    String password;

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }
```

I saw your Welcome.xhtml. You should use # instead of $.
so your welcome page should have something like this

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{userBean.password}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I changed the code you point out, but it still comes up error page, even the same error: Target Unreachable, identifier 'userBean' resolved to null.

Comment: did you specify faces servlet entry in web.xml?

Comment: <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

Comment: I think the error is in expression language. Try using 
`"#{userBean.VALUE}"` every where instead of "${userBean.VALUE}"

Comment: I have tried, never work. Anyway, thank you a lot, I may ask my teacher tommorrow.GN.

Comment: It only works when I configure the UserBean in faces-config.xml file like this:<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>userBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>Beans.UserBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>

Comment: You **do** have cdi configured/loaded as a lib do you?

Comment: Could you tell me specific steps about how to configure/load cdi as a lib?

Comment: @Kukeltje, You are right, I didn't configure the cdi, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

- I think the reason why I couldn't use annotation bean is that I didn't configure CDI in my application, because Tomcat doesn't support CDI by itself, you should manually add some external jar files to make it support. So here is the step I configure it.

---

1. Download weld-servlet.jar file, here is the link I downloaded it, you can also download it from internet.
   http://www.jsf2.com/using-cdi-and-jsf-2.2-faces-flow-in-tomcat/samples/weld-servlet.jar
2. Add this jar file to the directory ”/WEB-INF/lib“('d be better to build path)
3. Create a beans.xml file under "/WEB-INF", replace the existing code of the beans.xml file with the following code snippet:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd"></beans>`
4. One more thing, you must implement Serializble interface.

---

- Give you my whole program outline.
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwJ06.png)